# Files are not getting cached in ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, service-worker-events

I have migrated my existing website to PWA.
My website is very simple made using HTML, JQuery and javascript.
Previously the caching mechanism was dependent on `manifest.appcache`.
Now when I try to cache the files using service worker none of the file are getting cached.
I have checked my service worker is registered and everything seems fine but files are not getting stored in cache.
I tried clearing the cache but no help.
I am sharing my service worker code below since it is production code I can not share all file names.
I used this [site](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XT23X0Fjfk) to learn PWA.

```
const staticCacheName = 'site-static-v4';
const dynamicCacheName = 'site-dynamic-v4';
const assets = [
  "index.shtml",
  "fallback.html",
  "manifest.webmanifest"
];

// cache size limit function
const limitCacheSize = (name, size) => {
  caches.open(name).then(cache => {
    cache.keys().then(keys => {
      if(keys.length > size){
        cache.delete(keys[0]).then(limitCacheSize(name, size));
      }
    });
  });
};

// install event
self.addEventListener('install', evt => {
  //console.log('service worker installed');
  evt.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then((cache) => {
      console.log('caching shell assets');
      cache.addAll(assets);
    })
  );
});

// activate event
self.addEventListener('activate', evt => {
  //console.log('service worker activated');
  evt.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(keys => {
      //console.log(keys);
      return Promise.all(keys
        .filter(key => key !== staticCacheName && key !== dynamicCacheName)
        .map(key => caches.delete(key))
      );
    })
  );
});

// fetch event
self.addEventListener('fetch', evt => {
  //console.log('fetch event', evt);
  evt.respondWith(
    caches.match(evt.request).then(cacheRes => {
      return cacheRes || fetch(evt.request).then(fetchRes => {
        return caches.open(dynamicCacheName).then(cache => {
          cache.put(evt.request.url, fetchRes.clone());
          // check cached items size
          limitCacheSize(dynamicCacheName, 15);
          return fetchRes;
        })
      });
    }).catch(() => {
      if(evt.request.url.indexOf('.html') > -1){
        return caches.match('fallback.html');
      } 
    })
  );
});
```

Below is the screenshot of my empty cache storage.

[image]

Comment: Are you registering that service worker with a scope that includes all of your client pages? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#scope_and_control

Comment: @JeffPosnick no i am not registering with scope. It is working fine with localhost only in HTTPS i am getting this issue.

Comment: Even if you're not explicitly setting a scope, there's an implicit scope based on the location of your service worker in relation to where you client pages are served.

Comment: @JeffPosnick my service-worker is in root folder. It is working fine in localhost that is why i am not able to understand the issue.

Comment: are those URLs valid? I mean is the service worker trying to fetch URLs that are 404? Using addAll fails if any of the requests fail. Add a .catch to the promise chain to catch that.
Also set a break point in your code and follow your service worker logic for issues.

Comment: @ChrisLove I'll add catch condition and check. Do I have to add / in file names like "/index.shtml" ?

Comment: the slashes and if that is a default file for extensionless all matter. that is why I was wondering if you had 404 responses. I have seen that a lot in these situations.

Comment: @ChrisLove i am having 200 responses. It is not going to catch condition. I am having web worker in my existing code is it causing conflict ?